# How can I retrieve object from event on select tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I have a `select` tag that takes its options dynamically from an array of `governorate` data models like this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedGov" (ngModelChange)="onUpdateGov($event)">

    <option *ngFor="let gov of governorates">{{gov.code}}</option>

</select>
```

and the `onUpdateGov` method:

```
onUpdateGov(newGov) {
     console.log(newGov);
}
```

This method logs the governorate code, and I want to accept all gov object from event.
how can i retrieve the whole governorate object that user select

Comment: Java != Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `ngValue` to `option`:

```
<option [ngValue]="gov" ....
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ez2ahk?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

When the modelChange is fired you get the value of the option. If you don't explicitly bind a value, like you did, you retrieve the text value of the tag. You can either bind with `[value]=...` and get a string value or you can use `[ngValue]=...` and get a real object reference.

After using the `[ngValue]` binding your reference to the bound model will reflect the object instead of the string value (gov.code) as well. So you even might not need to use the event value but can rely on the bound property in your component.